# Checking post format during xmlrpc_publish_post

Tags: hooks, post-formats, twitter, xml-rpc

WordPress apparently stores post format information outside of the `$post` object. During `publish_post` this isn't (usually) a problem because you can check on formats via `get_post_format( $post->ID )` outside the loop.

This doesn't appear to work during `xmlrpc_publish_post` or `app_publish_post`. People have to be working around this to get plugin/theme functions working on mobile/desktop apps.

My specific code is below in case it's an error on my end.

```
function posse_twitter( $post_ID ) {
    error_log('Executing posse_twitter()');
    global $post;
    // check post format if necessary
    if ( get_post_format( $post->ID ) != 'status' ) return;
    error_log('posse_twitter() made it past format check');

    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $shortlink = wp_get_shortlink();
    $tweet_content = $post->post_content.' '.$shortlink;

    // ...run code once
    if ( !get_post_meta( $post_id, 'tweeted', $single = true ) ) {

        error_log('posse_twitter() not tweeted before');

        // require the relevant libraries
        require get_template_directory() .'/inc/posse/libraries/tmhOAuth/tmhOAuth.php';
        require get_template_directory() .'/inc/posse/libraries/tmhOAuth/tmhUtilities.php';
        $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
            'consumer_key'    => 'XXXXX',
            'consumer_secret' => 'XXXXX',
            'user_token'      => 'XXXXX',
            'user_secret'     => 'XXXXX',
        ));

        $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1/statuses/update'), array(
        'status' => $tweet_content
        ));

        error_log('posse_twitter() made it past tmhOAuth, should be on Twitter now');

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'tweeted', true );
    }
}

add_action( 'xmlrpc_publish_post', 'posse_twitter' ); 
add_action( 'app_publish_post', 'posse_twitter' );
add_action( 'publish_post', 'posse_twitter' );
```

`error_log()`s included since I've been debugging this. It's firing when `xmlrpc_publish_post` and  `app_publish_post` get hit, but it doesn't make it past the format check.

Update: This also doesn't work even if I save the post as a draft first (via XML-RPC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a variable mismatch.  Your function accepts `$post_ID`, but you don't actually use it.  You're instead trying to reference a global `$post` object and doing your post format check with `$post->ID`.  With the XML-RPC request, this won't work.

Rewrite your function to use `get_post()` to fetch a post object from the passed-in ID:

```
function posse_twitter( $post_ID ) {
    error_log('Executing posse_twitter()');
    $post = get_post( $post_ID );
    // check post format if necessary
    if ( get_post_format( $post->ID ) != 'status' ) return;
    error_log('posse_twitter() made it past format check');

    ...
}
```

Comment: Ugh, totally jammed myself up on that one. Worked perfectly, thanks!